# writeFileSync producing 0 bytes file - random

Tags: node.js, openshift, fs, writefile, livescript

A call to writeFileSync is producing a 0 bytes file at random.

The aim is to write a json to a file, then re-write it every time the json changes. And also load the json on startup. But the file keeps becoming 0 bytes long, most of the time it works then after a few days it becomes 0 bytes.

Code: LiveScript  https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/blob/master/src/db.ls
  Or converted to JavaScript https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/blob/master/db.js

```
   try
      db.DB = JSON.parse do
        require \fs .readFileSync "#dataDir/dump.json" \utf8
      console.log "==> Restored previous session from JSON file"
      db.DB = {} if db.DB is true
    Commands =
      bgsave: (cb) ->
        fs.writeFileSync do
          "#dataDir/dump.json"
          JSON.stringify db.DB,,2
          \utf8
        cb?!
```

With logging etc:

```
if fs.existsSync "#dataDir/dump.json" #check file exists - throws exception if exists and read fails
  #console.log "==> Found previous JSON file"
  try      
    db.DB = JSON.parse do
      require \fs .readFileSync "#dataDir/dump.json" \utf8
    console.log "==> Restored previous session from JSON file"
    db.DB = {} if db.DB is true
  catch 
    console.log "dump file locked, exit process"
    process.exit! 
else
  console.log "No existing dump file - #dataDir/dump.json "
Commands =
  bgsave: (cb) ->
    fs.writeFileSync do
      "#dataDir/dump.json"
      JSON.stringify db.DB,,2
      \utf8
    cb?!
```

Suggestion on how to debug or re-structure much appreciated.

Notes:
- Workaround - When I added an auto restart every 24 hours it fixed the problem.
- When it becomes 0 bytes, the code prints "dump file locked, exit process"
- the code is running on an openshift server
- looks to becomes 0 bytes when the server is auto restarted - not a manual restart, but when the server decides to trigger a restart

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate syntax tag since this is not apparently regular Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 js version https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc/blob/master/db.js - sorry -  it is livescript which is a fork of coffeescript

Comment: I'd rather say "LiveScript is a fork of Coco and an indirect descendant of CoffeeScript, with which it has much compatibility. "

Comment: are you sure you don't have any concurrent writes or stuff like that?

Comment: also `db.DB = {} if db.DB is true` is `db.DB &&= {}`

Comment: @Ven thanks for the thoughts. writeFileSync is synchronous - writeFileSync is always used to write  - by Tom: "Oddly enough "Synchronously" means "using the same clock" so when two instructions are synchronous they use the same clock and must happen one after the other. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean